# Почему строки не равны, если они одинаковые?

Tags: python

Я читаю из файла по строчно

```
file = open(records_file, encoding="UTF-8")
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        s = "\n"
        print(line == s)
        if not line:
            print("EOF")
            break
```

Файл выглядит так:

```
фцвфцв

аааа ааавыа

ацвфцв
```

А вывод у меня

```
False
True
False
True
False
False
EOF
```

Почему он так странно читает?

**UPDATE:**
Во-первых, дополню что файл формата *.csv, наверное это все-таки важно
А во-вторых
После того как добавил

```
print(repr(line), repr(s))
```

Вывод стал таким:

```
'\ufeff\n' '\n'
False
'фцвфцв\n' '\n'
False
'\n' '\n'
True
'аааа ааавыа\n' '\n'
False
'\n' '\n'
True
'ацвфцв' '\n'
False
'' '\n'
False
EOF
```

Comment: что именно странно и какие именно строки не равны? Прежде чем отвечать на мои вопросы, добавь строчку ``print(line)`` перед сравнением, чтобы знать, что там сравнивается. Возможно, вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Comment: @Эникейщик да я уже проверил что он выводит, вопрос в том, что пустую строку точнее строку с \n он  сравнивает с s = "\n" и выводит false хотя я ожидаю true

Comment: Я б даже сделал так: `print(repr(line), repr(s))` и тогда точно всё станет понятно.

Comment: @etoya А вы таки проверьте, напечатайте. Может быть такое, что вы читаете совсем не тот файл, который думаете, да что угодно может быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf а вот так понятно стало, спасибо

Comment: Покажите потом, что вывелось. Интересно же. С тем файлом, который вы показали, не должно быть такого вывода. Даже если где пробел закрался лишний.

Comment: @CrazyElf и вот почему у меня в начале файла '\ufeff' и как это тогда убрать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string

Comment: Ага, ну сравнение значит правильно работает, как и ожидалось ;)  Укажите кодировку, как указано по ссылке выше и всё заработает.